# enable-migrations Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem adding a new migration to an already migrations enabled project.

Adding previous ones worked.

As I conceptually refined my model, I reflected those changes to my already mapped classes.

When adding a new migration I received this error :

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.WriteLine(String message)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force,        Boolean ignoreChanges)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Do you receive the error when running add-migration in the console or when running update-database?